# How to change other elements when one element is hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set when p is hover it will affect the properties of img from another div inside a divs.

```
.class2 p:hover > .class3 {
    background: black;
}



<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS. You need JS for this.

Comment: in js i know how to do i tried with css but thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible in general (in CSS you can target just siblings or children, not parents).

In this case you can use `:hover` on parent element (`.class2`).

```css
.class2:hover + .class2 {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
        text in the second div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i needed only the text inside the p tag will have the hover and not all the class2 ..
but thanks ill change my html ..

Comment: @boris: Then it's not possible without changing HTML markup. If you need/want to help with HTML markup, just show us what you have, what you need, etc. I've worked with markup you showed us - and there was `p` the only one content of `.class2`... :-)

Comment: no its ok just wanted to know if there is a way..
i fix it by changing the html structure 
thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `pointer-events` in this case. I will edit your code a bit.

```css
<style>
    .class2{background: #ddd}
    div.class2 {  
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    div.class2 p {
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    div.class2:hover {
        background: yellow;
    } 
    div.class2:hover + .class2{
        background: yellow;
    } 
</style>
```

```html
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            text2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS post-processor library like **Axe**.

In this instance the CSS rule would use the `\` selector, like this:

```
.class2 p:hover \ .class3 {
    background: black;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.class1 {
  width: 240px;
  height: 160px;
}

.class2 {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
}

.class3 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.class2 p:hover \ .class3 {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

Comment: cant use js for this but thanks